# Fusionar commits en un repositorio local

Tags: git, vscode, git-commit, git-rebase

Tengo entendido por medio de "rebase interactivo" se pueden unir, encontré un poco de información en internet pero quería salir de la duda si hay mas métodos y como puedo hacer para unirlos.
https://www.oscarlijo.com/blog/fusionar-commits/

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Desunirlos? Una vez que les hiciste un squash? No podrías, ya que git no guarda en las revisiones producto del rebase información de las revisiones originales. No quiero decir que no puedas buscar otras formas como mirar información de reflog o si guardaste la rama original.... pero **a partir del resultado de un squash**, no puedes separar revisiones.

Comment: Perdón quise decir unir commit no desunirlos. EN EL MANUAL ESTA COMO  
git rebase -i HEAD~3 (el 3 viene de 3 uniones o como es me marie un poco con este dato) osea si quiero unir 2 commits tendría que poner al final  
git rebase -i HEAD~2?

Comment: ok.... ya te escribo la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres unir los últimos N commits, la forma de hacerlo es muy sencilla:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~N # reemplaza N por la cantidad de commits
git commit -m "Bla blah" # usa la descripción apropiada
```

Si es algo mas complicado como por ejemplo, quiero unir los 3 commits previos a los ultimos 2 (o sea, unir HEAD~4, HEAD~3 y HEAD~2 en una sola revision y dejar HEAD~ y HEAD como están), en ese caso lo mas sencillo es usar git rebase -i

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
# el primero se deja en pick, los dos siguentes en squash y los ultimos 2 en pick
# guardar, salir
# git rebase deberia detenerse en el momento de colocarle un comentario a las 3 primeras revisiones que van a quedar unidas
# colocar un comentario apropiado
# guardar y salir
# rebase termina de ejecutar
```

Y listo!

Moraleja: `git rebase -i` es muy potente. Incluso el primer problema se puede solucionar con él pero, como puedes ver, hacerlo de la forma que indico es mas sencillo (creo).

Comment: A que se refiere con "dejar HEAD~ y HEAD como están". tengo una duda HEAD~ y HEAD es como decir primer y ultimo commit? estoy practicando esta teoria, me cree un repo local con 6 commit y al escribir: "git rebase -i HEAD~5" me aparecen en el editor 5 commits (sin contar el primero) osea los 5 últimos intente cambiar con "git rebase -i HEAD~6" para ver si aparecía todos los commits pero me aparecio error.

Comment: `HEAD` en git es _siempre_ donde estás parado. `~` significa: el papá de (el primer papá si es un merge commit).

Comment: ahora tengo esto en vs code:                                                                                  
`pick f87d31e SEGUNDO COMMIT (Estructura html5)
pick a6f5f47 TERCER COMMIT (Estilo externo)
squash fc8329c CUARTO COMMIT (Titulo en README.md)
squash a7383d8 QUINTO COMMIT (Titulo en index.html)
pick c7e7ee1 SEXTO COMMIT (Metiendo README.md dentro de la carpeta raiz)`

Comment: Si tienes 6 revisiones en la rama (lineal) y escribes `git rebase -i HEAD~5`, estas pidiendo rebase desde la primera revision. La revisión que indicas al hacer un rebase se descarta... así que solo ves las 5 siguientes. La revision `HEAD~6` no existe en esa rama (porque solo tiene 6 revisiones) así que git te lanza el error. Si quisieras hacer un rebase hasta con la primera revisión creo que podrías hacer: `git rebase -i --root`

Comment: Lo máximo ahora tengo en terminal: `pick aaa0de9 PRIMER COMMIT (index.html, style.css, README.md - TODO EN BLANCO )
pick f87d31e SEGUNDO COMMIT (Estructura html5)
pick b22e8d3 TERCER, CUARTO Y QUINTO COMMIT (UNIDOS)
pick 457de8e SEXTO COMMIT (Metiendo README.md dentro de la carpeta raiz)` creo que ahora si se pudo realizar con éxito lo que buscaba unir commits ahora tengo otra duda si estos no son en un orden o en linea también podría unirlos?

Comment: git coloca los commits en el orden de la rama a la que le estas haciendo rebase. Las revisiones mas antiguas van arriba. Git va a ir aplicando las revisiones y sus acciones en la forma en la que las coloques de arriba a abajo (mensaje oculto en esas lineas: puedes reordenar las revisiones si es tu gusto).

Comment: Use el "git rebase -i --root" y me resolvio el problema de poder ver el primer commit. Ahora para ver si puedo unir commits (no seguidos) el editor me abrió una ventana para renombrar el commit hasta ahí todo bien, igual que los commits seguidos, hasta ahí todo bien hasta que me abrió dos veces el editor para renombrar aparentemente el mismo cambio, pero este proceso hizo que desaparezca mi primer commit y aparezcan los dos commits renombrados (los que me pidió renombrar). Mi duda es como puedo hacer este proceso para que no ocurra este fallo tomando en cuenta que estos commits no son seguidos

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Supongo que el editor se va a abrir cada vez que tengas un "grupo" de squashes. Si tienes 1 grupos, se va a abrir 2 veces..... o sea, git no va a adivinar el contenido del commit resultante del squash de varias revisiones, por eso se abre el editor.

Comment: Si quisiera unir 2 commit que no son necesariamente seguidos sino que están por ejemplo: commit2 + commit4 como podría realizarlo

Comment: te había comentado antes que puedes reordenar las revisiones en el editor que te abre `git rebase -i`. Puedes mover los dos commits para que queden juntos en el editor, el primero lo pones como pick, el segundo como squash.

Comment: entonces no se necesita que "2 commit" ambos tengan un "squash" solo bastaría con colocar un solo squash y el que esta antes de el para que se unan ambos?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. La forma de hacer squash es sencilla... para n revisiones _juntas_ que quieras convertir en una sola, la primera de ellas tiene un `pick`, las siguentes n-1 tienen `squash`. Puedes hacer varios grupos de squash (por ejemplo, squash de 3, 2 picks que se dejan iguales, luego un squash de otras 3), todo depende de como quieras manipular la historia.

Comment: Cuando digo **juntas** quiero decir que esten una detras de la otra, en lineas contiguas (como ya dije, las revisiones las puedes reordenar a tu gusto)

Comment: Y para que quede aun mas claro, en el ejemplo que acabo de dar (squash de 3, 2 picks y otro squash de 3) se logra con: pick, squash, squash, pick, pick, pick, squash, squash

Comment: Entonces siempre que se quiera unir (2 revisiones) la primera tendrá pick y la segunda squash. Y cuando se quieran unir (3 revisiones) la primera tendrá pick, luego las 2 que faltan con squash y así sucesivamente.? Gracias por la explicaciones 

Comment: Creo que ya lo entendi gracias por la ayuda